# Video renders black

Tags: rendering, video-sequence-editor

I am using Blender's Video Editor to edit and render videos for YouTube. When I render the video there is audio but the image is black. I've tried restarting a few times, and this has not happened to me before today. If there is an answer to this question already, please post a link. [image: Here's a screenshot i can add more if needed]

Comment: Is the **Sequencer** box enabled on the Scene>Post Porcessing section?

Comment: Yes it is @cegaton

Comment: When these problems arise, try "Hiding" the modifier and other strips until your video appears in the viewport.  If that fails, make a temp save and then delete each strip that's not the video proper until a picture appears.  If that also fails, it's possible Blender cannot read the video's codec or some other problem.  Convert the video to e.g. AVI, with an external application.

Comment: @Edgel3D The image appears on the view port but when I render it out the final video is black.

Comment: When rendering from the VSE make sure to select Blender's internal Render,  Also in the render panel at extreme right (little camera icon near the top left) open the "Post Processing" tab and see that the "Sequencer" box is ticked.  Without this you'll be rendering the 3D window, not the VSE.  If anything is in the Compositor and that box is ticked also, then you could be interfering with the output.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/81225/blank-final-rendering

Answer (score 2):

I seem to have figured it out, I had lossless output checked and that causes it to render out as a black image.